# How do I make a sticky footer banner in ScrollView? (Xcode)

Tags: xcode, scrollview, sticky, banner

I have a `ScrollView` hierarchy that looks like [image: this], the adView that I want to turn into a sticky footer banner being marked. How do I make the footer stick to the bottom of the screen at all times, even though I scroll down the page? My first thought was to pin it straight to the `mainView` or the `scrollView`, but if I place the `adView` anywhere else, it gets covered by the other views. I have looked for a proper tutorial but ended up empty handed. The information is either too old or irrelevant to what I'm trying to do. Can anyone point me to a good guide, or explain how to accomplish this? :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it:

1. Leave the adView where it is in the view hierarchy, remove its constraints.
2. Create an outlet for the adView. Then set its properties as follows:

   `adView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height - 50, width:
    self.view.frame.width, height: 50)`
3. Finally add the subview to the mainview:

   `self.view.addSubview(adView)`